# GNOME is not completely removed in Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, gnome

I installed GNOME on Kali Linux, then I decided to remove it and use Xfce 4. So I try

```
apt-get remove gnome-core
```

but GNOME is in the login menu and my system chooses GNOME file manager for inserting files and uses GNOME login panel when I turn my system on.
How can I remove GNOME completely?

Comment: It seems that you are trying to use Kali (from `https://www.kali.org`: __Kali Linux__ is an open-source, Debian-based Linux security distribution geared towards various information tasks, such as Penetration Testing, Security Research, Computer Forensics and Reverse Engineering. ) as a general purpose Linux system. This is unwise. Rather, install a supported Ubuntu release. You can build or install any of the Kali tools.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed GNOME on Kali Linux 2021.2 and selected GDM as the default display manager during installation.

Your command removes the package `gnome-core`:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove gnome-core
```

It only removes that package and any packages that depend on it. The following packages depend on `gnome-core`, so, if any of them are installed, they will be removed.

```
$ apt-cache rdepends gnome-core
gnome-core
Reverse Depends:
  gnome
  task-gnome-desktop
  kali-desktop-gnome
  gnome-audio
```

These packages, including `gnome-core`, are [metapackages](https://tools.kali.org/kali-metapackages). They depend on other packages for convenience of installing them, but contain no software themselves. When you remove them, no software is removed until you remove their dependencies too.

To remove the packages that were not manually installed and that no other installed package depend on, you can run `apt autoremove`:

```
$ sudo apt autoremove
```

To remove unused dependencies automatically when you remove a package, you can add `--autoremove` parameter:

```
$ sudo apt purge gnome-core --autoremove
```

This way, you do not need to run `apt autoremove` separately.

However, for instance, `gnome-shell` satisfies many dependencies. It is difficult for `apt` to figure out that `gnome-shell` is not needed anymore. You will need to remove it manually. The same goes for many other packages in this case: they are not removed automatically.

Before removing `gnome-shell`, it's better to login to Xfce. Otherwise, the desktop goes dark and you need to restart it after a while with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> or from your virtual machine software menu if you run Kali Linux in a virtual machine.

To remove all packages that were installed when GNOME was installed, we need to find out them. You can inspect `/var/log/apt/history.log` for that.

What command did I use to install GNOME? It could be installing any of metapackages mentioned above.

```
$ grep "^Commandline: apt.*install.*gnome" < /var/log/apt/history.log
Commandline: apt install gnome-core
Commandline: apt install network-manager-gnome
Commandline: apt install gnome-core
```

It looks like I ran the command twice. So I need to look for the first occurrence.

To show the log without clutter, so that you could just copy the list of packages to your `apt purge` command, you can use [the following useful script](https://askubuntu.com/a/176250/1112981):

```
$ perl -pe 's/\(.*?\)(, )?//g' /var/log/apt/history.log
```